# How to set multiple values with helm?

Tags: string, shell, kubernetes, command-line-interface, kubernetes-helm

Use `helm` install can set value when install a chart like:

```
helm install --set favoriteDrink=slurm ./mychart
```

Now want to set value like:

```
helm install --set aws.subnets="subnet-123456, subnet-654321" ./mychart
```

But failed:

```
Error: failed parsing --set data: key " subnet-654321" has no value
```

It seems that `helm`'s `--set` know comma `,` and check the next string as a key. So can't use in this case when set such string?

---

## Tested this way

```
helm install charts/mychart \
    --set aws.subnets={subnet-123456,subnet-654321}
```

Got error:

```
Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name
```

## This way works

```
helm install charts/mychart \
    --set aws.subnets="subnet-123456\,subnet-654321"
```

### Reference

> https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set

Comment: Reference link is now 404

Answer (score 21):

According to https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/1987#issuecomment-280497496, you set multiple values using curly braces, for example:

```
--set foo={a,b,c}
```

So, in your case it would be like this

```
--set aws.subnets={subnet-123456,subnet-654321}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That doesn't work for me. I posted the result to the question. And also added the right way.

Answer (score 16):

The CLI format and limitations can vary depending on what would be expected in a YAML version. For example, if the YAML manifest requires `fields` to be populated with a list of values the YAML would look like this:

```
field:
  - value1
  - value2
  - value3
```

This would be expressed in the helm CLI like so

```
--set field[0]=value1 --set field[1]=value2 --set field[2]=value3
```

*The documentation also refers to `--set field={value1,value2,value3}` working. In some cases that results in `Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name` which is why I provide the above suggestion*

There are also limitations to what characters may be used [per the documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/using_helm.md#the-format-and-limitations-of---set):

> You can use a backslash to escape the characters; `--set name="value1\,value2"` will become:
>
> ```
> name: "value1,value2"
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me in helm 2.13.1: `helm install deploy/traefik/chart --set externalIps[0]="a" --set externalIps[1]="b" --debug --dry-run` gives back `zsh: no matches found: externalIps[0]=a`

Comment: What about if your list items aren't a single value but a set of values, e.g. an ingress' paths list has a path, and a backend with a serviceName and servicePort. How can I do this and pass a full table of key-values, or just set one value and keep the rest?

Comment: @DavidFernandez You have to escape the square brackets to prevent your shell (zsh in your case) from interpreting them: `helm install deploy/traefik/chart --set 'externalIps[0]="a"' --set 'externalIps[1]="b"' --debug --dry-run`

Answer (score 9):

With [this](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/1817) change being merged, [Helm](https://helm.sh/) now supports using multiple `--set` command with `helm install` command.

### Taking from the link mentioned above:

> Manually tested, and looks awesome!

```
⇒  helm install --dry-run --debug docs/examples/alpine \
  --set foo=bar \
  --set bar=baz,baz=lurman \
  --set foo=banana

SERVER: "localhost:44134"
CHART PATH: /Users/mattbutcher/Code/Go/src/k8s.io/helm/docs/examples/alpine
NAME:   masked-monkey
REVISION: 1
RELEASED: Thu Jan 12 17:09:07 2017
CHART: alpine-0.1.0
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
bar: baz
baz: lurman
foo: banana

COMPUTED VALUES:
Name: my-alpine
bar: baz
baz: lurman
foo: banana
...
```

> As expected, the last --set overrode the first --set.

P.S: Upgrade your Helm version in case this doesn't work for you. It worked perfectly for me with ***Helm-v3.0.1***.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding this comment [How to set multiple values with helm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316330/how-to-set-multiple-values-with-helm?answertab=oldest#comment83620072_48317022) I used quotes and this worked:

```
--set aws.subnets="{subnet-123456,subnet-654321}"
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I am getting a strange `spec:
  [a b c]` when I do `helm install deploy/traefik/chart --set externalIps="{a,b,c}" --debug --dry-run`

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, if you're trying to set a list you can use:

```
--set aws.subnets="{subnet-123456,subnet-654321}"
```

be careful not to put any space between items. And check the type you're trying to set and make sure you're using the correct format.

You can also use:

```
--set-json='aws.subnets=["subnet-123456", "subnet-654321"]'
```

More information and examples can be found here:
https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/#options